# LINQ Select returns Null

Tags: c#, linq

I am reading a csv file and placing it in this structure:

```
List<Dictionary<string, object>> l = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
```

The CSV File contains:

```
cod_curso; name
3; language
5; math
6; physic
```

The code I have to do this is:

```
    string path = "test.csv";
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> l = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        var header = reader.ReadLine();
        var keys = header.Split(";");

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(';');

            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> d = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                d.Add(keys[i], values[i]);
                l.Add(d);
            }
        }
    }
```

To go through the structure I use the following:

```
foreach (var item in l)
{
   foreach (var dic in item)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(dic.Key + " " + dic.Value);
   }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is select the values of the dictionary by key, but it does not work for me, by doing:

```
var b = l.Select(a => a["cod_curso"]);
```

I get null.

"cod_curso" is a column of the csv file and is as a key in the dictionary

The next image is what I get in the debug

[image: Debug]

**How could I achieve what I am looking for? Or why does this happen?**

Comment: Try to debug it. What is the value of `l` and `a` on this line and inside the Select?

Comment: try `var b = l.Select(a => a.cod_curso]);`

Comment: @TheGeneral I get the following error, trying that: `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key 'cod_curso' was not present in the dictionary.'`

Comment: Then `cod_curso` is not one of the keys in the dictionary. If you could give a small sample of the CSV you're parsing, it may be as simple as a misplaced delimiter...

Comment: @HereticMonkey i edit my question whit csv example

Comment: From that, I see that there is a space between the semicolon and the next value; your key may be " cod_curso" or "cod_curso " rather than "cod_curso". I suggest `.Trim()`ming the value before adding it to the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want each dictionary to be created and added outside the inner loop, like:

```
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(';');
        var d = new Dictionary<string, object>(); // New dictionary for each line

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            d.Add(keys[i], values[i]);
        }

        l.Add(d);
    }
```